# ffmpeg vs avconv - Specifically use of lavfi in avconv

Tags: sound, video, ffmpeg, avconv

I have been trying to create a sine wave with `avconv`. I have read online that `avconv` is very similar to `ffmpeg` and much of the syntax of one should be almost identical to be used in the other. Searching around online tells me that generating a sine wave can be done in `ffmpeg` like so:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" test.wav
```

I have tried the same code in `avconv`, however it doesn't work and I get:

```
Unknown input format: 'lavfi'
```

I was wondering if there was a way to create a sine wave in `avconv` and if someone could clarify how `lavfi` commands can be used in `avconv`.

Comment: avconv does not have the sine filter (and a million other filters). Why not use ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan I suppose the reason why I'm using avconv is because avconv is in the raspbian apt repository whereas ffmpeg - I assumed that the functionality of avconv and ffmpeg are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`avconv` and `ffmpeg` do not have the same functionality: `avconv` is missing many features (`-f lavfi`) and filters (sine and aevalsrc). Because `avconv` lacks these I don't see a way to generate a sine with it.

Your Raspbian must be old because, according to [repology](https://repology.org/project/ffmpeg/versions), both Raspbian Stable and Oldstable use FFmpeg and not Libav (`avconv`).

Solutions:

- One obvious but possibly impractical solution is to upgrade your Raspbian and use `ffmpeg` from the repo.
- Compile `ffmpeg`.
- Find a static build. [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) offers `ffmpeg` for arm64, armhf, and armel. Maybe one of those will work on whatever Raspberry device you have.
- [Use `sox` or some other tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109038/linux-sine-wave-audio-generator).